# rails3-jquery-autocomplete foreign key

Tags: foreign-keys, jquery-autocomplete, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Hi I need help with setting up the rails3-jquery-autocomplete gem with a manually assigned foreign key in my database.

Here is what my models look like

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :reservations, :foreign_key => 'reserver_id'
   attr_accessible :login, :first_name, :last_name
 end

class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :reserver, :class_name => 'User'
  attr_accessible :reserver, :reserver_id, :reserver_login
end
```

The users table in my database has all of the columns

The Reservations Controller has

```
autocomplete :users, :login
```

Routes.rb has

```
resources :reservations do
  get :autocomplete_users_login, :on => :collection
end
```

And in the reservations view I have this

```
      <%= f.autocomplete_field :reserver_id, autocomplete_users_login_reservations_path %>
```

Now when I try and test it I see that the calls are being made in my javascript console but I get the error 500. For example I tried searching for xno which is in a login column of my users database.

```
GET http://0.0.0.0:3000/reservations/autocomplete_users_login?term=xno 500 (Internal Server   Error) jquery.js:8241
  jQuery.ajaxTransport.send jquery.js:8241
  jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js:7720
  jQuery.each.jQuery.(anonymous function) jquery.js:7246
  jQuery.extend.getJSON jquery.js:7263
  a.railsAutocomplete.fn.extend.init.a.autocomplete.source autocomplete-rails.js:17
  $.widget._search jquery-ui.js:6547
  $.widget.search jquery-ui.js:6540
  (anonymous function) jquery-ui.js:6335
```

Does this have anything to do with the fact that I am using foreign key in my database? If yes how should I structure my routing. I was following the gem documentation and tried to set it up so that I can look up the users table and list people by the login column of the users table, but so that the id gets returned and stored as :reserver_id once the user is selected. Previous code that worked with select field was

```
  <%= f.select :reserver_id, User.select_options, :prompt => true %>
```

where select_options method creates an array of login strings and id pairs in individual arrays.

I know that the solution is probably really easy, thank you for your help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was silly but it turned out it had nothing to do with the fact that the category table used a custom foreign key. My first problem was using plural version of the table name rather than the singular. Once I changed all references to users to user I noticed that javascript console wasn't throwing any exceptions at me so I figured that I had either broken everything and the call wasn't being made or it was going through and it wasn't rendering properly.

The presence of proper MYSQL calls in the console confirmed my suspicion. That's when I saw that the list was rendering way off to the right of my page probably due to strange styling happening somewhere else.

Bottom line is having a custom foreign key doesn't change usage of the gem at all. THe original table name should be used.